# Display data between two tables one-to-many

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, foreign-keys, crud, one-to-many

I'm doing a project which contains many tables in ASP.NET core 6 Entity Framework. I created models and generated the database. When I started to create the forms to make the CRUD operation I had a problem trying to relay data in the Index page.

```
public class Subject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SubjectName { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public virtual Classe Classe { get; set; }
    }

public class Classe
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id_class { get; set; }
        public string  ClassName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    }

public class ClasseController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SchoolContext _context;

        public ClasseController(SchoolContext schoolContext)
        {
            _context=schoolContext;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var classe = _context.Classes.ToList();
            return View(classe);
        }
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Classe cls)
        {
             _context.Classes.Add(cls);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }

public class SubjectController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SchoolContext _context;
        public SubjectController(SchoolContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            
            return View(await  _context.Subjects.ToListAsync());
        }

        public IActionResult Create()
        {

            ViewBag.data = _context.Classes.ToList();
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Subject subject)
        {
          
            _context.Subjects.Add(subject);
            _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
    }
```

The view of Subject:

Index

```
@model IEnumerable<MySchool.Models.Subject>
@{
}

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SubjectName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Classe.ClassName)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubjectName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Classe.ClassName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Create

```
@model MySchool.Models.Subject
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Grade</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SubjectName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="SubjectName" class="form-control" />
               
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label >Classe</label>
               
                @Html.DropDownList("classId", new SelectList(ViewBag.data,"Id_class","ClassName"),"Select name" )
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
    }
```

The view of Classe:

Index

```
@model IEnumerable<Classe>
@{
}

<a asp-action="Create">Ajouter</a>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Classe name</th>
           
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Id_class</td>
            <td>@item.ClassName</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Create

```
@model Classe
@{
}
<a asp-action="Index">Liste</a>
<form method="post">
    <label asp-for="ClassName">Nom du classe</label>
    <input asp-for="ClassName"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Ajouter"/>

</form>
```

DbContext

```
public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolContext> options):base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Classe> Classes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Classe>()
            .HasMany(b => b.Subjects)
            .WithOne();
        }
```

I can add classes without problem, but when I want to add Subjects I cannot find the name of the class.

Add classes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCf7B.png)

Add Subject
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiapA.png)

List of subjects
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tZYA.png)

My problem is the column of the ClassName is empty.

Why?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: When you create subject, have you checked the database if the foreign key be inserted into subject table successfully?

Answer (score 0):

If all data is stored in your database and EF Core doesn't load it, you probably need to `.Include()` things when fetching from database.

In your `ClasseController` and `SubjectController` when getting the list of objects from database do it like this:

```
// ClasseController -> Index()
var classe = _context.Classes.Include(x => x.Subjects).ToList();

// SubjectController -> Index()
return View(await _context.Subject.Include(x => x.Classe).ToList());
```

What happen is that EF Core for purposes of performance optimizations doesn't load this information. This can also be bypassed by using "Lazy loading" but this is heavily discouraged, since it has a huge performance impact on queries.

Also friendly suggestion. You should never access DbContext from a Controller or BusinessLogic class. Use DAOs with Unit of Work pattern.
So your architecture will look like this: Controller -> BusinessLogic class -> DAO -> Context

EDIT:
Also change your Subject class:

```cs
public class Subject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SubjectName { get; set; }
            
        [ForeignKey(nameof(Classe))]
        public int ClasseId { get; set; }
        public Classe Classe { get; set; }
    }
```

After you changed your class don't forget to migrate db again.

Comment: Hi , Thanks Martin for your answer and your sugestion, I tried to correct the code by adding Include() but It not works. If you see in my Subject model when I added the attribute Classe((public virtual Classe Classe { get; set; })) I made [NotMapped] , do you think is that the problem ?  If  I don't put    [NotMapped] it makes problem of the migration and I cannot find my tables .

Comment: This is the error :InvalidOperationException: The expression 'x.Classe' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

Comment: @user95 Oh yes my bad. Try removing [NotMapped] in Subject class and migrate the database again.

Comment: @user95 Also add another property "public int ClasseId { get; set; }" with [ForeignKey(nameof(Classe))]. This will create a new column with ClasseId so that you can easily search and link things together.

Comment: At first I make like that without  [ForeignKey(nameof(Classe))] , but when I made the migration I found a problem in the foreign key because in my project I have 10 tables .Ok I will make the changes and I will share the result .Thanks

Comment: It does not work, I find the same porblem of the first time ::: L'introduction d'une contrainte FOREIGN KEY 'FK_Examens_Subjects_SubjectId' sur la table 'Examens' peut provoquer des cycles ou des accès en cascade multiples. Spécifiez ON DELETE NO ACTION ou ON UPDATE NO ACTION, ou modifiez d'autres contraintes FOREIGN KEY.
Impossible de créer la contrainte ou l'index. Voir les erreurs précédentes.